# Change Keyboard Layout on Lock Screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I've been struggling with the following problem:

I am writing something in German during the day, therefore I change my keyboard layout to their QWERTZ style.
When I lock the screen or close my MBP it somehow locks the keyboard style as well.

When I come back and try to type my password, no success. My password has a certain special symbol that cannot be typed on the US keyboard using German layout.

I try the shortcut to change layout and nothing happens. At the top of the screen I can't see the flags either.

Is there a way to change keyboard layout on the Lock Screen?

Everytime this happens I have to reset the computer using the power button, which is bad to my open applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Users & Groups.

Click Login Options. Check the box next to **Show Input menu in login window**

You will then see a keyboard icon when your screen is locked.

Command + Click the keyboard icon should allow you to change the input.